# Parse value in array

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x, for-loop

I have a below array (please ignore brackets/braces):

```
 "items" :  [
    
    "metadata" : {
    
          "pod" : pod1
    
                 }
    
    "spec": {
        "containers" :  [
    
     {
    
      "image" : "image1"
       "name" : "name1"
      "image" : "image2"
       "name" : "name2"
]
```

Trying to insert values into CSV file.

My code snippet

```
def pods():
    api = '/v1/pods'
    response = callapi(api)
    test[]
    for i in response['items']:
        row_values = []
        if 'pod' in i['metadata'].keys():
            podname=i['metadata']['pod']
            row_values.append[podname]
        for container in i['spec']['containers']:
           for key, value in container.items():
               if 'name' in key:
                   containername=value
                   row_values.append[containername]
        for container in i['spec']['containers']:
           for key, value in container.items():
               if 'image' in key:
                   containerimage=value
                   row_values.append[containerimage]
                   test.append(row_values)
    with open('pod.csv', 'w', newline="") as write_obj:
       csvwriter=csv.writer(write_obj)
       for i in test:
         csvwriter.writerow(i)
```

code giving output like

pod1,containername1,containername2,containerimage1,containerimage2

but expected :

```
pod1,containername1,containerimage1
pod1,containername2,containerimage2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```py
def pods():
 api = '/v1/pods'
 response = callapi(api)
 test[]
 for i in response['items']:
   podname1=[]
   if 'pod' in i['metadata'].keys():
     podname=i['metadata']['pod']
     podname1.append[podname]
   for container in i['spec']['containers']:
      for key, value in container.items():
          if 'name' in key:
                containername=value
                test.append([podname1,containername])
 with open('pod.csv', 'w', newline="") as write_obj:
     csvwriter=csv.writer(write_obj)
     for i in test:
        csvwriter.writerow(i)
```

You don't need the `containername1` array because of the output you expect.

The finally approach you need is

```py
def pods():
    api = '/v1/pods'
    response = callapi(api)
    test = []
    for i in response['items']:
        if 'pod' in i['metadata'].keys():
            podname=i['metadata']['pod']
        for container in i['spec']['containers']:
           for key, value in container.items():
               if 'image' in key:
                   row_values = []
                   containerimage = value
                   row_values.append(podname)
                   row_values.append(containerimage)
               if 'name' in key:
                   containername = value
                   row_values.insert(1, containername)
                   test.append(row_values)
    with open('pod.csv', 'w', newline="") as write_obj:
       csvwriter=csv.writer(write_obj)
       for i in test:
         csvwriter.writerow(i)
```

But I do not test it, since the data you provide is incorrect format.

Comment: if I want to add one more value, for example, the 'image' key in array. should be like pod1 name1 image1

Comment: @kirank if you want more field, just rename podname1 array to row_values, then append any value 
what you want into it. finally test.append(row_values).

Comment: @kirank  You could mark an answer to be the answer. That could help others know this question is solved or who has the same question can refer it in the future.

Comment: modified code, but not giving expected results.

Comment: What is your current approach? You could post it at above.

Comment: edited above, see the output and expected results.

Comment: @kirank  have updated the answer, please try again.

Comment: Do you use key == image or key == 'image', they are different.

Comment: issue resolved after changing key == 'image' anyway thanks. I have one more query, can u pls suggest how can i handle the else part here if there is not key is available i want to pass "N/A" into CSV  (for all the keys)

Comment: You could just write else: row_values.append("N/A).

Comment: it's not working as expected, I added after if. It just adds some more N/A at the end of each row. let me check other aways. Thanks

if 'image' in key:
                   row_values = []
                   containerimage = value
                   row_values.append(podname)
                   row_values.append(containerimage) 
else:
                  row_values.append(N/A)